# Tangent portfolio weights without short sales?

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio, markowitz

Consider a mean-variance investor in a world with a risk-free asset.

Let $R_f>0$ be the return of the risk-free asset, $\mathbb{E}(R_i)>R_f$ the expected return of the risky asset $i$ and $SD(R_i)$ the standard deviation of the return of the risky asset $i$ for $i=1,...,N$.

Let $V$ be the variance-covariance matrix of the returns of all risky assets and $\bar{R}$ be their expectation.

Returns of risky assets can be positively correlated but not perfectly.

The weight of risky asset $i$ in the tangent portfolio is $x_i^\star=\frac{y_i}{\sum_{k=1}^N x_k}$ with $y_i=\{V^{-1}(\bar{R}-R_f)\}_{ii}$ if we allow for short sales. Hence, $x^\star_i$ can be **strictly positive** or **strictly negative** or **zero** (right?).

Question: which are the weights of risky assets in the tangent portfolio if we do not allow for short sales? Are they all **strictly** positive? If not, under which additional restrictions are they all **strictly** positive?

Comment: what is $y_i=\{V^{-1}(\bar{R}-R_f)\}_{ii}$ exactly, what source are you seeing the notation used in the question